# Data Modeling - Slow Changing Dimension type 2: How to deal with schema change (column added)?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

What is the best practice to deal with schema-changing when building a Slow Changing Dimension table?

For example, a column was added:

```
First state:
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+
|customerId|address              |updated_at         |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+
|1         |current address for 1|2018-02-01 00:00:00|
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+


New state with new column, but every other followed column constant:
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+------+
|customerId|address              |updated_at         |newCol|
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+------+
|1         |current address for 1|2018-03-03 00:00:00|1000  |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+------+
```

My first approach is to think that schema-changing means the row has changed. So I would add a new row to my SCD table:

```
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|customerId|address              |updated_at         |newCol|active_status|active_status_start|active_status_end  |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|1         |current address for 1|2018-02-01 00:00:00|null  |false        |2018-02-01 00:00:00|2018-03-03 00:00:00|
|1         |current address for 1|2018-03-03 00:00:00|1000  |true         |2018-03-03 00:00:00|null               |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

But, what if the columns were added, but for some specific row the value is null? For example, for row with customerId = 2, it is null:

```
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+------+
|customerId|address              |updated_at         |newCol|
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+------+
|2         |current address for 2|2018-03-03 00:00:00|null  |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+------+
```

In this case, I can take two approaches:

1. Consider every schema change as a row change, even for null rows (**much easier to implement, but costlier from a storage perspective**). It would result in:

```
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|customerId|address              |updated_at         |active_status|active_status_end  |active_status_start|newCol|
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|1         |current address for 1|2018-02-01 00:00:00|false        |2018-03-03 00:00:00|2018-02-01 00:00:00|null  |
|1         |current address for 1|2018-03-03 00:00:00|true         |null               |2018-03-03 00:00:00|1000  |
|2         |current address for 2|2018-02-01 00:00:00|false        |2018-03-03 00:00:00|2018-02-01 00:00:00|null  |
|2         |current address for 2|2018-03-03 00:00:00|true         |null               |2018-03-03 00:00:00|null  |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
```

2. Do a check for every row, and if it has an actual value for this new column, add it; otherwise, don't do anything to this row (**for now, I didn't come up with implementation to it, but it is much more complicated and likely to be error-prone**). The result in SCD table for row 2 would be 'row has not changed':

```
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|customerId|address              |updated_at         |active_status|active_status_end  |active_status_start|newCol|
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|1         |current address for 1|2018-02-01 00:00:00|false        |2018-03-03 00:00:00|2018-02-01 00:00:00|null  |
|1         |current address for 1|2018-03-03 00:00:00|true         |null               |2018-03-03 00:00:00|1000  |
|2         |current address for 2|2018-02-01 00:00:00|true         |null               |2018-02-01 00:00:00|null  |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
```

The second approuch seems more "correct", but am I right? Also, implement approuch 1 is much simpler. Approuch 2 would need some more complicated and has other trade-offs, for example:
a) What if instead of adding a columns, a columnd was droped?
b) From a query persperctive it is much more costlier.

I have done research on the subject and didn't fount this kind of situation being treated.

What is the standard approach to it? Trade-offs? Is there another approach I am missing here?

Thank you all.

Comment: The standard practice is to define the business logic, then work out the representation.  Do you need to differentiate between NONE and NOT-KNOWN? NULL encapsulates both, if you need to differentiate between them, you need to choose a representation beyond just using NULL. Do you need to differentiate between NOT-KNOWN-BECAUSE-PREDATES-SCHEMA-CHANGE and the more general NOT-KNOWN? Normally I'd say that's taking things too far, but you might need to. Once you know what logical information you're trying to encode THEN you can determine what its physical structure would be.

Comment: Our option two is the *only meaningfull*. Also why do you think it is complicated? Simple ignore all customers that have the new attribute `NULL`.   In practice often you need to integrate *the history*  of the new column, here starts the complexity..

Comment: @MatBailie in this *simplest* case it is known that the new attribute is defined for *all* customer starting with some point in time. If the attribute is set the change time is explicite, if not *you know it* . So IMO no need fo rstoring the *nothing was changed* row in the SCD table. Of course other opinions are possible and may be valid;)

Comment: @marmiteBomber I personally loathe and detest Implicit data. Knowing a date and recording a date in the standard structure are two very different things.

Comment: Than you guys. I ended up implementing the second option, will explain that and summarize your thoughts in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @MarmiteBomber and @MatBailie comments. Based on your comments I ended up implementing the second option, because (summary of your thoughts):

1. The second approach is the only one meaningful.
2. Implementation is a consequence of business logic, not necessarily a standard practice. In our case, we didn't need to differentiate types of nulls, so the right approach was to encapsulate known non-existing values as null, as well as unknown values, etc.
3. Be explicit.

The second approach also needed to add a check (is the new column present in the row?) in write time, but it saves complexity in query time, and storage. Since SCD is "slow" and this case is rare (schema changes happen, but not "every day"), adding the check in write time is better than in query time.